# Add specific class to child from parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I got some list items with a child element. What I want is that each child of the li get a class based on their parents id class. But all the elements are getting the id of the first li.

HTML

```
<ul>
  <li class="test post-91 other">
    <a class='link'></a> 
  </li>
  <li class="test post-43 other">
    <a class='link'></a>
  </li>  
</ul>
```

JQUERY

```
var id = $('.link').closest('li').attr("class").split(' ')[1];
id = id.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
id = "class-"+id;
$('.link').addClass(id);
```

I want the  elements to get the number of the "post-" from their parent li.

https://jsfiddle.net/f5Lqzzew/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One more Solution : 
Here all li can be taken in loop and then find the anchor inside it and assign the class to it.

```
$("ul li").each(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('class').split(' ')[1].replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
    $(this).find("a.link").text('class-' + id).addClass("class-"+id); // demo purposes only
});
```

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f5Lqzzew/5/)

Comment: Nice, actually my first thought was to use an each function, but i was setting something wrong, I wasn't able to achieve the expected result.
Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Welcome and enjoy coding

Answer (score 2):

You need to calculate the class based on the specific `li` element itself. To do this, you can pass a function to the `addClass()` method. Try this:

```
$('.link').addClass(function() {
    var id = $(this).closest('li').attr('class').split(' ')[1].replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
    return 'class-' + id;
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/f5Lqzzew/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Update the script to do a loop on all li's. This is working...

```
<script>
$('ul li').prepend("<a class='link'></a>");

$('li').each(function(i,v){
  var v = $(this)[0].className;
  v = v.split(' ')[1];

    v = v.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
    v = "class-"+v;
  $(this).children('a.link').addClass(v);
  $(this).children('a.link').text(v);
});

</script>
```